# ASP MVC Return SP result to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, return-value

Using VS 2013 and writing my first ASP MVC app. I have a controller:

```
 // GET: CreateBundlesAndCartons
    public ActionResult CreateBandC(Int32 id)
    {
        string ReturnMessage;
        ReturnMessage = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            //string connectionStringName = this.DataWorkspace.CooperData.Details.Name;
            connection.ConnectionString =
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSAContext"].ConnectionString;
            string procedure = "PSA.dbo.CreateBundlesAndCartons";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 300;

                command.Parameters.Add(
                    new SqlParameter("@JobID", id));
                SqlParameter ErrorString = new SqlParameter("@ErrorString", ReturnMessage);
                ErrorString.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                ErrorString.Size = 4000;
                command.Parameters.Add(ErrorString);

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Save Outout Param
                ReturnMessage = ErrorString.Value.ToString();

            }
        }
        return Content("You requested the to create bundles and cartons for job ID " + id.ToString() + "<br />Result: " + ReturnMessage + "<br /> ");
    }
```

I want to display the results to the user and them give them ability to return to the jobs view.

I tried this as my return value:

return Content("You requested the to create bundles and cartons for job ID " + id.ToString() + "
Result: " + ReturnMessage + "
 Return to Jobs");

This displays the results and the link:

[image: Result]

But the link points to http://localhost:59971/Jobs/CreateBandC/~/Jobs/ instead of http://localhost:59971/Jobs/

How can I fix that?

Is there a better way to return the results?

I'm under some time pressure, so this approach would do for now, but I'd like to actually figure out how to return a more complex type and nicer view

Thanks

mark

Comment: how is your "Return to Jobs" link being created? In the stored procedure you are calling? If not, then your question isn't showing it to us.

Comment: @TSmith - it's in the question. It's part of the ReturnContent string

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the posted code that is creating an <a href> tag, for the "Return to Jobs" link. Your sproc is probably generating the <a> tag, which is what BeautifulCoder is referring to. Post the sproc code.

Comment: The stored procedure returns a regular string of unformatted ascii text

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this requires database changes to fix the link. This is typically a result of poor design and tight coupling. So, go in the database and change the `a` tag in your stored procedure to get the desired result.

Comment: OK. I don;t understand that reply at all. All I'm trying to do is get back to a view and return a view. It has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: Check `ReturnMessage` it is coming from an out param `ErrorString`

Comment: What should I be checking? i know it's coming from an output parameter (by design) and that's working.